# How to do a mod rewrite for this?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Currently, when my users are buying from my shop it will go to:

http://localhost.com/shop/index.php?shopid=1&item=2

How would I make it to where it would be like

1 being shopid, 2 being item.

http://locahost.com/shop/1/2

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ shop/index.php?shopid=$1&item=$2 [L,NC]
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

This option is in your httpd.conf file.

change it from

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```